# Choose unique numbers from different sets

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, combinations

Suppose that there are `n`, possibly equal, non-empty sets. The problem is concerning choosing unique `n` numbers such that first number from first set and so on.

First, is there an algorithm to check if I can do it? And, second, How can I actually choose the numbers?

Examples
$$
\begin{align}
s1 &= \{5,6\}\\
s2 &= \{5\}\\
s3 &= \{6,7\}
\end{align}
\text{In this case, the choices are possible and they are 6,5 and 7 respectively}
$$
$$
\begin{align}
q1 &= \{1,2,3,4\}\\
q2 &= \{2,3\}\\
q3 &= \{2,3\}\\
q4 &= \{3\}\\
\end{align}
\text{In this case, we cannot choose since q2,q3 and q4 have only three possiblities}
$$

I thought of this algorithm to check if it can be done, but I don't know if it's correct

```
union all n sets. if size < n => CANNOT CHOOSE, else continue
union all smallest n-1 sets. if size < n-1 => CANNOT CHOOSE, else continue
union all smallest n-2 sets. if size < n-2 => CANNOT CHOOSE, else continue
and so on ...
if reached the smallest set => you can choose unique numbers from the set
```

I don't think this is correct for all cases and I don't know what to do with equal sets. I hope there is something better. An Algorithm to actually choose will be great!

Comment: Related: [Hall's marriage theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall's_marriage_theorem) gives a necessary and sufficient condition for this to be possible, but does not immediately translate to a feasible algorithm. (In particular it states that every case where it is _not_ possible can be recognized with a counting argument of the kind you give for the second example).

Comment: Are the sets finite?

Comment: If you google for "marriage theorem algorithm", various relevant-looking results pop up.

Comment: Thank you Henning Makholm. I will look into it

Comment: If you want $n$ **different** elements, there is a well-developed theory around your question. I suppose, though, if you wanted different elements, you would have **said** "different elements". I can't imagine what you could possibly mean by "$n$ unique elements" when $n\gt1.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for what's usually called a *[system of distinct representatives](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/283368/families-of-sets-determination-of-sdr-system-of-distinct-representatives)* or SDR. A theorem of M. Hall states that the sets $\{S_i\mid 1\le i\le n\}$ have an SDR iff rhe union of any subcollection $S_{i_1},\ldots,S_{i_k}$ has size at least $k$.

However, this condition is not always easy to apply directly; here's an efficient way to find an SDR. Build a bipartite graph where one side consists of the $n$ singleton sets, the other side consists of the given sets, and connect $\{i\}$ to $S_j$ iff $i\in S_j$. An SDR is a perfect matching in this graph, so you can efficiently find an SDR (or show it doesn't exist) using an algorithm for solving the bipartite matching problem, such as the [Hungarian algorithm.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm)